# Is it possible to adjust screen scroll speed?

Tags: command-and-conquer-red-alert

I'm playing Command and Conquer: Red Alert, but one thing is making it particularly difficult and that is the speed that the screen scrolls - this is unrelated to the speed the mouse pointer moves, but it seems that the moment your cursor touches the edge of the screen it begins scrolling rapidly in that direction.

There are no menu options to change the scroll speed unlike in the later games.

Is it possible to adjust screen scroll speed?

Comment: I beleive you can also use your arrow keys to scroll the screen

Comment: @Ender Not in the original Red Alert you can't unfortunately, works in all the later C&Cs though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I read online this fixed the issue.

Go to your RA1 directory, run rasetup.exe and enable Back Buffer in Video Memory.

Once you do that restart the game and it should be fixed.

Comment: This certainly makes it a little less twitchy, it's still a bit fast but this has more than halved the scrolling speed. Thanks!